# converting files to .PDF without downloading any libraries

Tags: vb.net, pdf, converters, tiff

Is it possible to convert a .tif file to .pdf without downloading any 3rd party libraries? I have an issue with my .tif files that are being viewed in a Tiff Viewer. The image looks very stretched horizontally and almost unreadable. I've spent hours and hours trying to fix it somehow, but am unable to.

I've tried to use a PictureBox to view them, however, in most cases I have more than a single page, so that kind of goes out the window. I also have a web browser in my application which I use to view .pdf files - and they look great! I'm looking to see if there's a way to convert .Tif to .pdf within my application - so that user does not have to Save As PDF.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If i need to use a library - any recommendations?

Comment: "I have more than a single page, so that kind of goes out the window" - Why? [Image.SelectActiveFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.selectactiveframe(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @TnTinMn - i tried to do the picture box, the problem with that is, my application has limited width/height so when .tif file is being displayed inside of it, it gets cut off vertically and horizontally. I'm trying to do something along the line of Web Browser - when i view .PDF files, it's being shown nicely with a scroll bar.

Comment: It is not difficult to put the Picturebox in a scrollable control and resize the PictureBox to match the contained image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution may be to install a PDF printer and send each file to it. That would require some 3rd party software but should be easy to do.

Comment: is there a way to display .tif file with one of the existing components in vb.net

Comment: What about manually setting the aspect ratio of the Tiff viewer in an fixed size popup dialogue?